# How to put padding top in singlechildscrollview on keyboard appears

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, keyboard

I using this library `keyboard_actions` to display `Done` button on above keyboard when on click on `textfield`. Now the issue is `keyboard` displays but `done` portion is overlapping/ Above on `textfield` although `textfield` is inside `SingleChildScrollView`. I want to put `padding` when `keyboard` appear so that i can see `textfield`. I have an attached screenshot so that you can understand.
[image: Screenshot]

> TestPage.dart

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final TextEditingController mobileNumber = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final FocusNode _nodeText1 = FocusNode();
  late bool _passwordVisible;
  final TextEditingController firstName = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController lastName = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController confirmPassword = TextEditingController();
  String pWord = "";
  List gender = ["Male", "Female"];
  late String genderChoose;

  KeyboardActionsConfig _buildConfig(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardActionsConfig(
      keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.IOS,
      keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
      nextFocus: false,
      actions: [
        KeyboardActionsItem(
          focusNode: _nodeText1,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _TestPageState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    genderChoose = gender[0];
    _passwordVisible = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var box = GetStorage();
    var lang = translator.activeLanguageCode;
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window)
          .copyWith(boldText: false, textScaleFactor: 1.0),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: KeyboardActions(
          config: _buildConfig(context),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 90.0, right: 90.0, top: 25.0),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'images/aa.png',
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 20.0),
                            child: Card(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'SIGN UP',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('First name'),
                                        Row(
                                          children: const [],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 5.0,
                                            right: 5.0,
                                            top: 12.0,
                                            bottom: 12.0),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                          controller: firstName,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Last name'),
                                        Row(
                                          children: const [],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 5.0,
                                            right: 5.0,
                                            top: 12.0,
                                            bottom: 12.0),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            controller: lastName),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 15.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Mobile Number'),
                                        Row(
                                          children: const [],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 5.0,
                                            right: 5.0,
                                            top: 12.0,
                                            bottom: 12.0),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                                RegExp("[0-9]")),
                                          ],
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          focusNode: _nodeText1,
                                          controller: mobileNumber,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                                              hintText: "5xxxxxxxx",
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  color:
                                                      TuxedoColor.bodyColor)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Gender'),
                                        Row(
                                          children: const [],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 5.0,
                                          right: 5.0,
                                        ),
                                        child: DropdownButton(
                                          hint: const Text('Select Gender'),
                                          value: genderChoose,
                                          isExpanded: true,
                                          underline: const SizedBox(),
                                          icon:
                                              const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              genderChoose = newValue as String;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          items: gender.map((valueItem) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                value: valueItem,
                                                child: Text(valueItem));
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Password'),
                                        Row(
                                          children: const [],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 5.0,
                                            right: 5.0,
                                            top: 12.0,
                                            bottom: 12.0),
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: [
                                            TextFormField(
                                              keyboardType:
                                                  TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                                              controller: password,
                                              obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                                              decoration:
                                                  InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                                      hintText: "*******",
                                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          color: TuxedoColor
                                                              .bodyColor)),
                                            ),
                                            Positioned(
                                              right: 0,
                                              top: -10,
                                              bottom: 0,
                                              child: IconButton(
                                                icon: Icon(
                                                  _passwordVisible
                                                      ? Icons.visibility
                                                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                                                ),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _passwordVisible =
                                                        !_passwordVisible;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Confirm Password'),
                                        Row(
                                          children: const [],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 10.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                          border:
                                              Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: 5.0,
                                            right: 5.0,
                                            top: 12.0,
                                            bottom: 12.0),
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: [
                                            TextFormField(
                                              keyboardType:
                                                  TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                                              validator: (value) {
                                                if (value!.trim().isEmpty) {
                                                  return "This Field is required";
                                                }
                                                if (value != pWord) {
                                                  return "Confirmation password does not match with the entered password";
                                                }
                                                return null;
                                              },
                                              controller: confirmPassword,
                                              obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                                              decoration:
                                                  InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                                      hintText:
                                                          "Confirm Password",
                                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey)),
                                            ),
                                            Positioned(
                                              right: 0,
                                              top: -10,
                                              bottom: 0,
                                              child: IconButton(
                                                icon: Icon(
                                                  _passwordVisible
                                                      ? Icons.visibility
                                                      : Icons.visibility_off,
                                                ),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _passwordVisible =
                                                        !_passwordVisible;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 20.0,
                                        right: 20.0,
                                        top: 20.0,
                                        bottom: 30.0),
                                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                                      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                                          height: height * 0.060, width: width),
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        style: ButtonStyle(
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                                  Colors.red),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        child: Text(
                                          'SIGN UP ',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16.0,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'Already have account? ',
                                          style: TextStyle(),
                                        ),
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Sign in',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.red,
                                              decoration:
                                                  TextDecoration.underline,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70565026/13997210) hope its help to you.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Yes i also tried that but between textfield and keyboard showing big gap.

Comment: can you share full code

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I have share my code. Note: I have to put padding top 190.0 for other content widget

Comment: why you add extra top padding ?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil To test if there are some widgets before textfield in future that's why

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil If you want more information i can send you updated code (But it's lengthy) ?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil i have updated my code.